# how to install Mysql & tomcat on mac os x 10.5.8

Tags: mysql, macos, tomcat

Hi can some one provide me how to install both om my mac osx 10.5.8

Hi can some one provide me how to install both om my mac osx 10.5.8

Ok this what I have done

Downloaded MySQL version 5.5.22.dmg for Mac OS X 10.5 (x86, 64-bit) from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Installed  three files from it after mounting....

1.MySQL -version.pkg installed it by double clicking on it 
2.mysqlstartupitem.pkg installed it
3. MySql.prefpane - after installing it says it doesn't work on intel based Mac

After that I have no idea whati need to start

Regarding tomcat JAVA_HOME WAS the problem;(

Comment: What have you tried so far? We'll help, but only if we think you've done some research first (this will be why people have downvoted your question, I would think).

Comment: Also, try Macports: http://www.macports.org/

Comment: Can any one help me?

Comment: @halferi want to install MySQL directly rather than to use xampp or mamp servers on mac